# counted the cards carefully again

Tags: meaning, adverbs

a) He counted the cards again carefully.

b) He counted the cards again**,** carefully.

c. He counted the cards carefully again.

d. He counted the cards carefully**,** again.

The question about each of the above sentences is whether he had counted the cards carefully before or is it possible that this was thr first time he counted them **carefully**?

Answer (score 2):

Both c and d are more likely to mean that the previous count(s) were careful.

If you wanted to really emphasize that the previous count was also careful, you could say

> Once more, he counted the cards carefully.

If you wanted to say that this was the first really careful count, you could say

> He counted the cards again, this time carefully.